# How to convert nested lists into "standard" lists?

Tags: list-manipulation

What is the easiest way to convert a nested list in a "standard" list?

For istance how can I fastly convert

```
{{16.5807}, {17.1458}, {16.1343}}
```

into

```
{16.5807,17.1458,16.1343}
```

?

Thanks for your help, probably it is very basic, I'm a beginner with Mathematica.

Comment: See `Flatten` in the documentation

Comment: Consider reading the tutorial on [Nested Lists](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/NestedLists.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Code:**

```
(*Sample data*)
data = {{16.5807}, {17.1458}, {16.1343}}

(*Operation*)
Flatten @ data
```

**Output:**

> {16.5807, 17.1458, 16.1343}

**Reference:**

[Flatten](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Flatten.html)

**Guide:**

[List Manipulation](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/ListManipulation.html)